# Problema em remover/adicionar classe no Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando fazer com que um botão remova ou adicione uma classe no body, porém esta dando o seguinte erro ao clicar no botão "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null"

```
var body = document.querySelector('div.single-news');
var button = document.querySelector('button#skin-btn');
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    body.classList.toggle('light-skin');
});
```

O ideal seria fazer o código com JS puro.

Atualizado com o HTML:

```js
var menu = document.querySelector('div.single-news');
var button = document.querySelector('button#skin-btn');
botao.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var open = menu.classList.contains('light-skin');
  menu.classList.toggle('light-skin');
});
```

```html
<body class="entry-header single-news">
  <button class="night-mode-btn" id="skin-btn">
    <span class="night-mode-btn__text">Modo noturno</span>
  </button>
  <h1 class="entry-title">
    {{ post.title }}
  </h1>
  <time class="entry-postedon">
    <span class="screen-reader-text">Publicado em</span> 
    {{ post.post_date|date("j \\d\\e F \\d\\e Y") }} às {{ post.time|date("H\\hi") }}
  </time>
  {% if post.thumbnail %}
  <div class="entry-cover-image">
    <img data-dynsrc="['{{ post.thumbnail.src('img-16x9-760x428') }}']" data-fullscreen-url="{{ post.thumbnail.src('large') }}">
  </div>
  {% endif %}
</body>
```

Comment: Poste também seu html :)

Comment: Estarás a colocar esse script no `head` antes de o browser ter lido o HTML? Coloca o script no final da página, antes de `</body>`.

Comment: Isso. Estou colocando o <script> no final do codigo, antes do </body>.
Atualizei como html

Comment: Você está usando var menu = document.querySelector('div.single-news') e não existe nenhuma div com essa classe no seu html. Existe essa classe em body....

Comment: André, o seu problema é bem simples, você não possui uma `div.single-news` e sim `body.single-news`, então o seletor `div.single-news` não retorna nada,

Comment: Era só isso mesmo! :O Muito obrigado, Leon e Tobias!